# What allows bare class instances to have assignable attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to fill in a gap in my understanding of how Python objects and classes work.

---

A bare `object` instance does not support attribute assignment in any way:

```
> object().a = 5
# or
> setattr(object(), 'a', 5)

AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I assume that this is because a bare `object` instance does not possess an `__dict__` attribute:

```
> '__dict__' in dir(object())

False
```

However a bare `object` instance *does* have a defined `__setattr__` attribute, so this is a bit confusing to me:

```
> '__setattr__' in dir(object())

True
```

---

An instance of a regular empty class on the other hand has full ability of attribute assignment:

```
class B(object):
    pass

> B().a = 5
> setattr(B(), 'a', 5)
```

---

My question is: what inherent difference between an `object` instance and a `class B(object)` instance allows the latter to have assignable attributes, if `B` inherits directly from `object`?

Comment: You'll actually notice that `object.__setattr__` and `B.__setattr__` are the exact same method.  It either needs a slot named `a` or a `__dict__` in order to set a value for `a`.  Your object instance has neither.

Comment: "However a bare object instance does have a defined `__setattr__` attribute, so this is a bit confusing to me" why? It's not relevant. The relevant detail is the `__dict__`.

Comment: @FrankYellin it also handles descriptors. e.g. `property`

Comment: The magic happens [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c8749b578324ad4089c8d014d9136bc42b065343/Objects/object.c#L1374) if you are interested. Basically, the `object.__setattr__` will check if there is a `__dict__`, among other things. `object` instances don't have a dict (or any of the other things that might allow `obj.attr = val` to work, e.g. an appropriately named `__slots__`, or a descriptor in the class).

Comment: Although this is how `object.__getattribute__` works, it is an informative, pure-python implementation if C is not something you understand, from the descriptor [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invocation-from-an-instance) , setting an attribute works similarly

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.  I was trying to keep my answer simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `object()` class is like a fundamental particle of the python universe, and is the base class (or building block) for all objects (read everything) in Python. As such, the stated behavior is logical, for not all objects can (or should) have arbitrary attributes set. For example, it wouldn't make sense if a `NoneType` object could have attributes set, and, just like `object()`, a `None` object also does not have a `__dict__` attribute. In fact, the only difference in the two is that a `None` object has a `__bool__` attribute. For example:

```
n = None
o = object()

type(n)
>>> <class 'NoneType'>

set(dir(n)) - set(dir(o))
>>> {'__bool__'}

isinstance(n, object)
>>> True

bool(n)
>>> False
```

Inheritance from `object` is automatic, and, just like any other means of inheriting, one can add their own class methods and attributes to the child. Python automatically adds the `__dict__` attribute for custom data types as you already showed.

In short, it is much easier to add an object's `__dict__` attribute than to take it away for objects that do not have custom writable attributes (i.e. the `NoneType`).

**Update based on comment:**

Original comment:

> Would it then be safe to assume that it is `__setattr__` that checks for the existence of `__dict__` and raises an exception accordingly? –
> bool3max

In CPython, the logic behind `object.__setattr__(self, name, value)` is implemented by Objects/object.c `_PyObject_GenericSetAttrWithDict` (see [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9cf6752276e6fcfd0c23fdb064ad27f448aaaf75/Objects/object.c#L1284)). Specifically, it looks like if the `name` argument is a string, then the object is checked for a `__dict__` object in one of its slots and makes sure it is "ready" (see [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9cf6752276e6fcfd0c23fdb064ad27f448aaaf75/Objects/object.c#L1300)).

The readiness state of the object is determined by the `PyType_Ready()`, briefly described and quoted from [here](https://ref.readthedocs.io/en/latest/understanding_python/type_system/PyTypeObject.html#creating-a-python-type-in-c):

> Defining a Python type in C involves populating the fields of a PyTypeObject struct with the values you care about. We call each of those fields a “slot”.
>
> On[c]e the definition is ready, we pass it into the PyType_Ready() function, which does a number of things, inclulding exposing most of the type definition to Python’s attribute lookup mechanism.

Comment: although note, `bool(object())` also works

Comment: Would it then be safe to assume that it is `__setattr__` that checks for the existence of `__dict__` and raises an exception accordingly?

Comment: Yes, see update to my answer.